# How to search and download specific Windows updates on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of specific updates that we want to install on computers that are not connected to the internet. We have been using PowerShell and would like to stick to it. I am open to other options. My question is how can I feed a list of updates to a program and then that program takes that list and searches and downloads the files from https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/

These files would then be transferred to an offline computer with a USB and updated with a different program.

Comment: I recommend PowerShell and the Save-KBFile script found [here](https://gist.github.com/potatoqualitee/b5ed9d584c79f4b662ec38bd63e70a2d)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician this looks worth of an answer. Want to add it?